# Graphic of function similar to Sin(x) but with scaled size

Tags: functions, visualization

I wont to build a graphical representation of numbers, as "waves":

Similar as the graphic of `sin x` but for each number N it gets bigger and bigger 
crosses the `x axes` in the multiples of N,
with `y` from -N to +N
and repeating every 2N.

I found this tool usefull for the drawing:

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sin%20x,%202%20%28sin%20x%29)

Can some one help me with finding the function ?

Comment: something like $y(x)=x \sin(x)$ ?

Comment: this scales it only in Y direction but  the period stays the same.

Comment: I do not exactly understand what you want, but sth like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin+x%2C+x*%28sin+%282pi+x%29%29%29) ?

Comment: Do you mean that there is a different "wave" function for each $N$, or there is only one function which takes all the $N$ at once ?

Comment: N is rational number, for each N the resulting graphics should have the same shape, but scaled in all directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you mean, but I can give you a direction to look.

To change the points where the graph crosses the x-axis, change sin(x) to sin(a*x) for some a. For example sin(pi*x) or the other way round using a division: sin(x/pi).

To make the graphic bigger for bigger x, try adding a factor related to x (like x itself, x^2, sqrt(x), e^x). For example: x*sin(x)

Comment: got it by trail and error but you described it nicely

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

f(x) = n*(sin (pi*x/n))

[http://www.wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28sin%20%28pi%2ax%29%29,%202%2a%28sin%20%28pi%2ax/2%29%29%20,%203%2a%28sin%20%28pi%2ax/3%29%29)